# Getting Logged in User details from Firebase real time databse

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase real-time database and registered user details with Email and Password authentication.

Now, I can successfully do login and logout for registered users.

Now, I have to get details of currently logged in user.
My database structure is as below :

```
 {
  "UserInfo : " : {
    "User ID : CxQNTJwnoleIk9M1iYMT9TsrJst2" : {
      "-Kvb_W0YWX7M8dPF7Kn9" : {
        "contact" : "8888888888",
        "email" : "visu@gmail.com",
        "firstname" : "Vish",
        "lastname" : "Mo",
        "password" : "vish",
        "strUserId" : "CxQNTJwnoleIk9M1iYMT9TsrJst2"
      }
    },
    "User ID : e1VCGeshWfOeptzzj4kP1POtmhk2" : {
      "-KvbTM1Jtzn3r9V7II47" : {
        "contact" : "9999999999",
        "email" : "ja@gmail.com",
        "firstname" : "Ja",
        "lastname" : "Mo",
        "password" : "ja123#",
        "strUserId" : "e1VCGeshWfOeptzzj4kP1POtmhk2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For example, If I have logged in with email: visu@gmail.com then I want to get all the details of that user.

How can I do it ??

Ya, I can get Email and Displayname as below :

```
 FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
 txtUsername.setText("Welcome, " + user.getDisplayName() + "\n" + user.getEmail());
```

But, I want to get all the details of that user from above-specified database structure. Please, guide me. Thanks.

Comment: is this ur real-time database structure ??

Comment: yes, Its firebase database structure.

Comment: This structure seems not good. You can read this. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Comment: Thanks sir, for your suggestion. I will definately go through it.

Answer (score 1):

When you do as this:

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
txtUsername.setText("Welcome, " + user.getDisplayName() + "\n" + user.getEmail());
```

It's just your Authentication field, not your database.
As first, you should define these field by:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// ...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

In your db structure:

```
mDatabase.child("UserInfo : ").child("User ID : CxQNTJwnoleIk9M1iYMT9TsrJst2").child("-Kvb_W0YWX7M8dPF7Kn9").child("contact").getValue();
```

In the end, refactor your db structure by simple word. UserID, Email, Password is redundant because which can be taken by Authentication Field.

Read more: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 1):

try this. hope this will work

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserInfo")
     .child(user.getUid())
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    UserClass curUser =  dataSnapshot.getValue();
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

And Finally, I have done as below :

```
private void showData() {
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(ProfileActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Getting data...");
    progressDialog.show();
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserInfo : ").child("User ID : " + firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            txtFname.setText(user.getFirstname());
            txtLname.setText(user.getLastname());
            txtEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
            txtPassword.setText(user.getPassword());
            txtContact.setText(user.getContact());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Couldn't get data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener);
}
```

Created a method, in which loaded ProgressDialog first, then took a Database refrence and initialized it up to my databse node with getting UUid from **FirebaseAuth** instance. Attached **ValueEventListener** and inside method : **onDataChange**, used instance of **DataSnapshot** to get value for my **User** class. and Finally displayed fetched data to my textviews.

Thanks all for your efforts. upvoted.

**EDIT** : 
My new structure is as below :

```
{
  "UserInfo : " : {
    "User ID : I6wWODplkNXqAhSCRZsH6sjf4mM2" : {
      "contact" : "9999999990",
      "email" : "dhaval@gmail.com",
      "firstname" : "Dhaval",
      "lastname" : "Patel",
      "password" : "dhaval123",
      "strUserId" : "I6wWODplkNXqAhSCRZsH6sjf4mM2"
    },
    "User ID : Nf4kDsxAXYbclt16HahkzsYABWE3" : {
      "contact" : "9999999999",
      "email" : "bandish@gmail.com",
      "firstname" : "Bandish",
      "lastname" : "Mehta",
      "password" : "bandish123",
      "strUserId" : "Nf4kDsxAXYbclt16HahkzsYABWE3"
    }
}
```